# Dropdown data from DB using AngularJS and ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, erb

I am trying to make a dropdown that will grab current sites that are loaded from the DB using AngularJS in a ruby on rails project

I have dashboard.html.erb and SitesController.js

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="SiteIndexController">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
  <option ng-repeat="x in name" value="{{x.name}}">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>

</div>
```

That example gives me the name1,name2,name3.

```
angular.module('MetronicApp')
  .controller('SiteIndexController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$http", "$timeout", "$state",
    function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout, $state) {

      $scope.names = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"];

      $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        // initialize core components

        $scope.sites = [];
        $scope.selected = $scope.sites.name

        $scope.getSites = function(){
          $http.get("/sites").then(
            function success(response){
              $scope.sites = response.data.content;

              $scope.selected = $scope.sites
              $scope.selectpicker = $scope.sites.name
            },
            function failure(response, status) {
              alert("Something went wrong! - index");
            }
          )
        };

        $scope.getSites();
    });
}])
```

The $scope.sites = response.data.content adds the sites into it. I want the SITE_NAME value from that and have it in the dropdown.

When I change it from names to sites, it is coming in empty. What do I need for it to return the SITE_NAMEs from the $scope.sites?

Comment: You should only use `ng-options`, not `ng-options` and `ng-repeat`. See [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).